# Drupal: How do I manually print Taxonomy Images

Tags: php, image, drupal, taxonomy, vocabulary

Here is the code I used to print taxonomy images per specific vocabulary using [Taxonomy Image](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image):

```
<?php
$vid = 19;
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node,$vid);
$new_terms = array();
if ($terms) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term = taxonomy_image_display($term->tid) as $image);
    print '<div class="color">' . $image . '</div>';
    $new_terms[] = $image;
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken. Did you mean:

```
<?php
$vid = 19;
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node,$vid);
$new_terms = array();
if ($terms) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $image = taxonomy_image_display($term->tid);
        print '<div class="color">' . $image . '</div>';
        $new_terms[] = $image;
    }
}   
?>
```

This is correct PHP and should work.

Comment: Thanks RotHorseKid. Only thing is that it only works when I'm logged in. I flushed the cache in Drupal and the browsers, didn't work.

Comment: Yeah. I too forget that all the time.